# Adding a close icon inside input with close action

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

im having troubles trying to work something out and would be great if someone could lend me a hand in the following:

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/44zAy/3/ (UPDATED: added multiple ones which then gets confused, any help on this would be great. also added click function to close when clicking on the icon)

when you click inside the input it extends, and when click out goes back to normal which is what i want however what im trying to add is:

a) add the font awesome icon inside the input once its extended
b) ability to click on the x icon to close the input back to the normal size, the same in how it does when you click out of the input currently

the code so far (basic example) is as follows:

JS

```
var inputWdith = '200px';
var inputWdithReturn = '68px';     
jQuery('.resize-close').hide();

jQuery('.resize-input').focus(function(){
 jQuery(this).animate({
  width: inputWdith
 },400);
 jQuery('.resize-close').show();
}); 
jQuery('.resize-input').blur(function(){  
 jQuery(this).animate({
  width: inputWdithReturn
 },500);
 jQuery('.resize-close').hide();    
});
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" class="resize-input">
<a class="resize-close"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a>
```

How the input is currently is using an absolute position on my development as it extends out over other inputs

Thanks in advance!

Comment: isn't `(b)` working already? i think you can achieve `(a)` by setting a negative margin to the button  http://jsfiddle.net/DKW7H/  .Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Is the "x icon" the same as the "font awesome icon"?

Comment: Ive updated the fiddle, i need the icon inside the input at the end if possible. its also getting confused when i have more than 1 input on there.

Comment: updated http://jsfiddle.net/44zAy/6/ - would be good if i could expand both at any one time though.

Comment: @JamesBrandon if you use jquery `next` when selecting `resize-close` icon then i think you will be fine e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/3AuhN/ . Having both expanded and blur will work if you check in blur if inside another field

Comment: how would i check on that? so far i have this: http://jsfiddle.net/44zAy/10/ thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply add a negative margin to the `.resize-close` class:

```
.resize-close {
    margin-left: -24px
}
```

...and then update the blur handler to be a click handler instead:

```
jQuery('.resize-close').click(function(){  
    jQuery('.resize-input').animate({
        width: inputWdithReturn
    },500);
    jQuery('.resize-close').hide();    
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/44zAy/5/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/44zAy/7/ - i have made some changes - do you know how i can make it so it allows to open more than 1 input at a time?

Comment: Remove the `blur` event handler, otherwise it'll "close" the input when you click/tab into another input. http://jsfiddle.net/44zAy/8/

Comment: I know but i need it to close if you click out of the input or tab out of it as well which done that with the blur, any ideas and thanks for your time :)

Comment: would using bind be the solution?

Comment: If you need to close on a click or tab to another text box, how would you _ever_ have two open at the same time?

Comment: this is just part of a table, which has other inputs